# json schema validation error with LocalDateTime-array found, string expected

Tags: java-8, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, localdatetime

I am validating date of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` using json-schema. But I am getting below error:

```
message= array found, string expected
```

json-validator dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.networknt</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.49</version>
</dependency>
```

json-schema

```
"dateInvoiced": {
  "type": "string",
  "format": "date-time",
  "minLength": 1
}
```

Json

```
  {
    "dateInvoiced": "2021-12-01T07:16:31Z"
  }
```

Code for validating json against json schema

```
 public void validateJsonDocument(String payload, ChargeType chargeType, 
  List<Error> errorList)
   throws JsonProcessingException {
   try
   {
  InputStream schemaAsStream =
          CreateOrderEventDerivation.class
                  .getClassLoader()
                  .getResourceAsStream("jsonSchemas/" + chargeType.getValidationFileType());
  JsonSchema schema =
          JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(SpecVersion.VersionFlag.V7).getSchema(schemaAsStream);

  ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
  om.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategies.KEBAB_CASE);
  JsonNode jsonNode = om.readTree(payload);
  Set<ValidationMessage> errorSet = schema.validate(jsonNode);
  for (ValidationMessage error : errorSet)
  {
    String[] errorObj = error.getMessage().split(PaymentServiceConstants.COLON);
    errorList.add(new Error(errorObj[0], errorObj[1]));
  }
  log.info("END: BaseRequestValidator.validateJsonDocument Size of errors:{}", errorList.size());
}catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

I don't want to check any specific Date format. Is there any other way to handle java 8 LocalDateTime in json schema because in past I haven't face any issues with `java.util.Date`.

Comment: Can you add the schema, example JSON &  networknt validate code snippet of a simplified example? I'm asking because the current error of `array found` hints at a mistake before the string format definition comes into play.

Comment: @Byted I hope I have added all required things you asked for.

Comment: Can you log your payload? I am unable to reproduce your error.

Comment: @JANO {
  "invoice": {
    "eventPayload": {
      "orderNo": "787787777",
      "orderInvoices": [
        {
          "documentType": "0001",
          "dateInvoiced": "2021-12-01T07:16:31Z",
          "lineDetails": [
            {
              "alternateItemID": "",
              "lineCharges": [
                {
                  "chargeAmount": "22.90",
                  
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          
        }
      ],
      "createServiceId": ""
    }
  }
}

Comment: This is minified version of my payload

Comment: Could you also post the schema corresponding to that payload? This way we can rule out that the error comes from something other (e.g. the arrays in the JSON).